# I am getting back the index # and "undefined" from these if/for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, scrape

So I am looking in my database right now and there is 3 articles, so the x should represent the number 3 for the for loop later. This code is supposed to add articles to the database if they are freshly scraped. In the titles[] array there is 100  items (scraped from news.google). When I execute the code, it seems like it correctly finds the index # of the titles[] list (which is the 55,68,60  repeats), but it shows up as this:   (I don't even want the index # being displayed in console either, I want the title of article to be displayed. I had to shrink some of this code, too long)

```
55
68
60
55
68
60
55
68
60
55
68
60
55
68
60
55
68
Complete.
Successfully added article: undefinedto the database.
Successfully added article: undefinedto the database.
Successfully added article: undefinedto the database.
Successfully added article: undefinedto the database.
Successfully added article: undefinedto the database.
Successfully added article: undefinedto the database.
```

And here is my code:

```
// accessing the database
function DatabaseTime(sourcesDates, timeAdded, links, titles, descriptions) {
    sourcesDates = sourcesDates;
    links = links;
    titles = titles;
    descriptions = descriptions;


    // put counter so params can access this in it's object scope, use it for the for-loop
    // object operator. MEAT OF THE BURGER
    var databaseOperation = function (sourcesDates, timeAdded, links, titles, descriptions) {
        var scanParams = { TableName: "Rnews" }
        // using code to setup for accessing the 2nd list
        db.scan(scanParams, function(err, scanData) {   // scanData = the 2nd list we are going to work with
            //use this array later to hold the unique items
            var arrayCheck = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < scanData.Items.length; i++) {
                arrayCheck.push(scanData.Items[i].title);
            }
            var index = 0;
            var counter = 0;
            var x;


            for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    index = 0;
                    x = 0;
                for (var x = 0; x < arrayCheck.length; x++) {

                    //if (titles[i] === arrayCheck[x]) {
                    if (titles.indexOf(arrayCheck[x] === -1)) {
                        index = titles.indexOf(arrayCheck[x]);
                        console.log(index);
                        var autoParams = {
                            TableName: "Rnews",
                            Item: {
                                title: titles[index],
                                source: sourcesDates[index],
                                url: links[index],
                                description: descriptions[index],
                                lastAddOrUpdated: dbTimeStamp,
                                timePublish: timeAdded[index]
                            }
                        }
                        Insert(autoParams, titles);
                    }
                    }
                }
            function Insert(autoParams) {
                db.put(autoParams, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Successfully added article: " + titles[i] + "to the database.");
                });
            }
            console.log("Complete.");
        });
    };
    databaseOperation(sourcesDates, timeAdded, links, titles, descriptions);
}
//// END

DatabaseTime(sourcesDates, timeAdded, links, titles, descriptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. (printing the index):
   You're doing `console.log(index);` in the first `if` statement, which prints the numbers.
2. (undefined problem):

you're trying to access `titles[i]`. the problem is that neither `items` nor `i` are defined here. What do you see in your console?

You're also trying to pass `items` to the `Insert` function as the second argument, but the function declaration doesn't include a second argument.

if you want to print the item's name, you could either pass more information to your function like this:

```
function Insert(autoParams, currentItemsName) {
            db.put(autoParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Successfully added article: " + currentItemsName + " to the database.");
            });
```

and then call it:

```
Insert(autoParams, titles[i]);
```

instead of:

```
Insert(autoParams, titles);
```

Or you could use the data that is already available to you inside the function and print that, which is the better option in my opinion.

```
function Insert(autoParams) {
            var currentItemsName = autoParams.Item.title
            db.put(autoParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Successfully added article: " + currentItemsName + " to the database.");
            });
```